# UWP Does RichEditBox read only .rtf files?

Tags: c#, uwp, richeditbox

I try to add a file content to my RichEditBox using this method :

```
myRichEditBox.Document.LoadFromStream(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, streamFile);
```

And that is how I fill my streamFile variable :

```
public static async void openFileAsync(string pathFolder, string file)
    {
        Windows.Storage.StorageFolder folder = await Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync(pathFolder);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("folder : " + folder.Path);

        Windows.Storage.StorageFile fileOpen = await folder.GetFileAsync(file);
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("file : " + fileOpen.Path);

        Windows.Storage.Streams.IRandomAccessStream stream = await fileOpen.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);

        streamFile = stream;
    }
```

I have no exception that rises but the richBoxEdit text is unreadable (characters are unreadable).
I want to read txt files.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: What file type and format is the file you're trying to read?

Comment: Oh sorry I forgot to mention that... I just try to read a .txt file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use `Stream` to read contents of the File, You can use the method Below. This will return the contents of the file as `Text`.

```
internal async Task<string> UsingStream(StorageFile sampleFile)
{
    IRandomAccessStream stream = await sampleFile.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
    ulong size = stream.Size;
    string text = string.Empty;
    using (var inputStream = stream.GetInputStreamAt(0))
    {
        using (var dataReader = new DataReader(inputStream))
        {
            uint numBytesLoaded = await dataReader.LoadAsync((uint)size);
            text = dataReader.ReadString(numBytesLoaded);
        }
    }
    return text;
}
```

See the [Official Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/quickstart-reading-and-writing-files#reading-from-a-file) for Reference

However if you want to directly load the Text instead of stream, Use Below.

```
string fileText = await FileIO.ReadTextAsync(sampleFile);
```

And then assign the data to `RichEditBox` like below.

```
MyRichEditBox.Document.SetText(Windows.UI.Text.TextSetOptions.None, await UsingStream(sampleFile));
```